# How can I get an Action Key without an InputAction?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I would like to create the text "Press {InteractKey} to {Interact}."

How can I get the key that is bound to my Interact action binding ("F") without using an InputAction? I want to get the key without having to trigger an event.

So in the end my text would say something like "Press F to do the thing."

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the action key by getting input settings, then getting the action mapping my name, I can then break the InputActionKeyMapping and get the key from that.

[image]